# Syntax error near unexpected token 'GPIO.BCM'

Tags: gpio

I am having a problem with a (apparently) very commonly used script for relay automation.

The script is as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# init list with pin numbers

pinList = [2, 3, 4, 17, 27, 22, 10, 9]

# loop through pins and set mode and state to 'low'

for i in pinList: 
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT) 
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

# time to sleep between operations in the main loop

SleepTimeL = 2

# main loop

try:
  GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
  print "ONE"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL); 
  GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
  print "TWO"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);  
  GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
  print "THREE"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
  print "FOUR"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
  print "FIVE"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
  print "SIX"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)
  print "SEVEN"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.output(9, GPIO.LOW)
  print "EIGHT"
  time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print "Good bye!"

# End program cleanly with keyboard
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"

  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have the latest Wheezy image as well as Phyton (2.6, 2.7 & 3, GPIO-0.5.2a & 0.5.5) .. When I use

`./test.sh` (my script is named "test")

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.sh", line 5, in <module>
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setmode'
```

So then I use:

```
bash -x text.sh
```

and get

```
+ import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
test.sh: line 2: import: command not found
+ import time
test.sh: line 3: import: command not found
+import time
test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token 'GPIO.BCM'
test.sh: line 5: 'GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

I have also tried

```
GPIO.setmode(BCM)
```

with the same results.

Any suggestions would be immensely appreciated. I am a complete n00b with the pi and this has been driving me nuts for....days.

Comment: You are probably using an old version of RPi.GPIO.

Comment: I have the latest Wheezy image as well as Phyton (2.6, 2.7 & 3, GPIO-0.5.2a & 0.5.5)

I'm actually in the process of flashing a new card with a fresh install. It just seems that something has got to be corrupt, somewhere, as it all "should" work.

Comment: There appears to be a space before the #! in the first line.  You should remove the space.

Comment: Do you have any other files in this dir? Also, can you run: python -c "import RPi.GPIO as GPIO; print GPIO.__file__" and paste the result?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make test.sh run the following

> sudo python YourPythonCode.py

remember to make it executable

> chmod 755 test.sh

copy all your listed code into YourPythonCode.py

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the extension to .py as a friend had suggested earlier, too, but it still doesn't seem to be functioning. 
I think now I may have addressed another issue in that I believe it may have been that I wasn't executing commands as root, earlier?
Only thing is, now, when I execute commands such as
./test.ph
I get:
-bash: ./test.sh: no such file or directory

Comment: you need to change to the directory where the code is located. to view the files in a directory, type "ls -al" 
To change to a directory, use the "cd" command e.g. "cd Documents/mycodes"

you know you can run the python codes directly right?? does it work like that??

type "python /your-code-path/YourPythonCode.py"

Comment: I did know you could run them directly, yes. Unfortunately none of mine were doing even that. 
Thank you very much, again. 
I am updating my new install on a second card, which is a larger card, anyway. 
I'll update how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  #!/usr/bin/python
> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
> ```

The mistake is right here, in the first line. A [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) must begin at the very first character of the script, while in your code it's preceded by a space character. This makes the script be interpreted by your default shell, rather than a Python interpreter.

Remove the space to make first two characters `#!`, and the error should vanish.

Answer (score -1):

Rename your script to `test.py` and then run it with `sudo python test.py` (sudo is needed for GPIO access)

Comment: GPIO works perfectly fine without root access for me.

Comment: @Ruslan that's new, back in 2015 (!), sudo was required